# visual studio 2010 & expression studio 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What is the correct order of installing visual studio 2010 and expression studio 4.0?]
In light of the WPF expression blend link not being present on the open lnk - i'm thinking that maybe the order of software installation is important. i am thinking first
expression studio 4.0 is first and then the visual studio 2010 is next because visual studio needs to know what links to find in order to place if any in its IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Order is not important. IMHO. But when I istall this apps, first I setup VS. its just habit, nothing more.